# Gnuplot: Unwanted white space on the left side in legend key box

Tags: gnuplot

Please have a look at the attached plot created from Gnuplot. I am facing two issues with it.

1) The empty white space in the left side of the key box (legend box). Is there any way to remove that extra empty white space? Neither I want to lose the key box nor compromise on the Greek letters used. Also, note that final output format has to be eps.

2) There is also too much space between the y-axis and the y-label. How to optimize it?
Please help.

[Gnuplot_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tVto.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

Gnuplot doesn't know the exact width and height of the ultimately formatted strings. It rather tries to approximate the width based on some font information. That does also happen when using e.g. the `qt` terminal with a title containing only very narrow letters:

```
set terminal qt
set key box
plot x title 'iiiiiiiiiii'
```

[image]

That becomes even more complictated when TeX strings are involved. Use the `width` parameter for `set key` with a narrow value to decrease the key's width. You must manually estimate the actual value to use:

```
set terminal qt
set key box width -6
plot x title 'iiiiiiiiiii'
```

[image]

The same argumentation applies to the positioning of `xlabel` and `ylabel`. Here, you must use the `offset` parameter to correct the position:

```
set xlabel 'xlabel' offset 0, -0.5
set ylabel 'ylabel' offset 0.5, 0
```

Comment: @ Christoph Thanks. It worked both for empty space in key box as well as for the label offset. One minor query: The key box often touches the texts in the legends. Now I know (from your solution) how to control the width in the horizontal direction, but how to increase height of the key box just by a little. I want a thin white space between the upper key box boundary and first legend; and lower key box boundary and last legend. I tried these commands: set key box vertical spacing 0.6; set key box horizontal spacing 0.6. But it did not worked as desired.

Comment: Also, when the plots come in journals where they are down-scaled, the first and the last legend often appear to be touching the key box boundaries. Any fix for this?

Comment: Yes, read `help set key` ;) and then use e.g. `set key height 0.2`