# gnuplot - distance between columns in a key

Tags: gnuplot

How can I reduce the distance between columns in a key?
I use this code:

```
    set key horizontal maxrows 5
    set key font 'Times-Roman,18'
```

But I receive this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467559/2604213, that applies also for multiple columns

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!)